# Swift 2d array empty after HealthKit function call - thread issues

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm populating a twodimensional array with `HealthKit` data. It's working fine as long as the function loops through the 30 days. outside of that function the array is empty because `HealthKit` data is loaded in background and everything else executes before.

How can I wait until the data is loaded so I can access the data inside the arrays?

Here's what's happening inside my `ViewController`

```
            print("function call starting") // 1
        // Populate 2DArrays
        self.hkManager.getTotalCalories(forDay: 30) {caloriesValue, date   in
            //check if caloriesValue is nil, only do something if it's not
            guard let caloriesValue = caloriesValue else { return }
            let dateValue = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: date!, dateStyle: .short, timeStyle: .none)
            print("will append") // 7 (31x)
            self.caloriesArray.append([(dateValue,caloriesValue)])
    }

        print("function call done") // 2
        print(self.caloriesArray.count) // 3

        hkManager.getWeightData(forDay: 30) {bodyMassValue, date   in
            // Check if bodyMassValue is nil, only do something, if it's not
            guard let bodyMassValue = bodyMassValue else { return }
            let dateValue = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: date!, dateStyle: .short, timeStyle: .none)
            self.bodyMassArray.append([(dateValue,bodyMassValue)])
        }

        do {
            self.age = try hkManager.getAge()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error calculating age: \(error)")
        }

        print(bodyMassArray) // 4
        print(caloriesArray) // 5
        print(age!) // 6
}
```

I've added numbers behind the print statements to make clear what get's executed when.

The functions I'm calling look like this:

```
    func getTotalCalories(forDay days: Int, completion: @escaping ((_ calories: Int?, _ date: Date?) -> Void)) {
    // Getting quantityType as .dietaryCaloriesConsumed
    guard let calories = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .dietaryEnergyConsumed) else {
        print("*** Unable to create a dietaryEnergyConsumed type ***")
        return
    }

    let now = Date()
    let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: -days), to: now)!
    var interval = DateComponents()
    interval.day = 1

    var anchorComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: now)
    anchorComponents.hour = 0
    let anchorDate = Calendar.current.date(from: anchorComponents)!

    let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: calories,
                                            quantitySamplePredicate: nil,
                                            options: [.cumulativeSum],
                                            anchorDate: anchorDate,
                                            intervalComponents: interval)
    query.initialResultsHandler = { _, results, error in
        guard let results = results else {
            print("ERROR")
            return
        }

        results.enumerateStatistics(from: startDate, to: now) { statistics, _ in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let sum = statistics.sumQuantity() {
                    let calories = Int(sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.kilocalorie()).rounded())
                    completion(calories, statistics.startDate)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }
    healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

Anyone any ideas what I need to do?
Thanks! :)

Comment: You don't wait. You do whatever you need to do with the data in the closure.  Or, if you need to execute once two or more asynchronous events are complete you can use a `DispatchGroup` and `notify`

Comment: But the closure behaves kind of like a loop. When I print self.caloriesArray for example I get about 31 prints to the console.

Comment: as an alternative to using a dispatch group you could use a `didSet` observer on the array and update your calculations each time a new element is added to the array.

Comment: Dispatch group won't work because the completion is called multiple times so my original post is incorrect :(.  If you give me a use case for what you are doing I can write some code that helps solve the problem, but you likely will either have to return a dictionary [Date:Int?] from the completion after enumeration has finished or you will have to do your calculations while the data is coming in.

Comment: I'm looking for the easiest way obviously, I'm still learning. What I want to do is basically just ask healthkit for weight and calories consumed for the last x days (I want the days to be a user setting). I then want to calculate the burned calories like this spreadsheet does: https://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/comments/8pap61/a_new_tdee_calculator/

I solved it "quick and dirty" by using a 'DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter'. I'd appreciate your help to simplify and improve things though. I can give you access to the private github repo if you give me your username